# If Muslim university student sins in a non-Muslim country (by e.g. drinking alcohol), will his repentance be accepted?

Tags: tawba

If a Muslim university student who was born in a non Muslim country has been in a company with non-Muslims, he has sinned out of ignorance (by e.g. drinking alcohol) with them, then regrets what he has done, repents and gets away from the company will his repentance be accepted? Are these non-Muslims going to be held as witnesses to the sins If a Muslim repents?

Comment: What makes you think your repentance will not be accepted?

Comment: A college kid goes to a party. It’s not the crime of the century, is it? Make tawbah.

Answer (score 1):

What prevent him from repentance?
Only we have to fulfill the conditions to have correct repentance:

1. Regretting what we did of sins
2. Having stronge will to avoid getting back to sins
3. And of course, taking off from the sins

Even if we did sins again, we should repent again.

We should be ready for going to the last day. Every day of our life is a chance for repentance.

Very important to note the strong effect of company and to keep goo

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model I recommend you to take our [tour] and check our [help]. Your answer could be more helpful if you added some evidences to support your claims (see [answer]).

Answer (score 0):

Asalamualaikum.

No matter how much sins you do or how many of them. Repentance is always accepted. Its Allah's greatness that He accepts repentance. The person should repent by heart and having intention of not repeating the thing again.

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE. Answers should be elaborate and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour] in the [help], and refer to [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your answer is in the first aya of the first surah :
Bismillahi Ar Rahman Ar ***Raheem***
In the name Allah, the most beneficent, ***the most merciful***

Allah's mercy is infinite.  If you are sincere in your ***tawba*** (repentance), InshAllah you will be forgiven.

Second, sins against yourself are more easily forgiven than sins against others.  One of the hadiths states "do not leave the dunya with the haq (rights) of others".  When you consume intoxicating drinks you are inflicting 'Zulm' (tyranny, harm) on your own body with these poisons.  Several ayas in the Quran mention that your own organs or skins will testify against you on the day of judgement.  So, the non-muslims who you shared intoxicating drinks with don't have to testify against you since your own organs will be doing the testimony.  Allah entrusted you with the stewardship of your body.  It does not belong to you but to Allah.

Also, time that your mind is in a drunk or senseless state is time that is not devoted to worshiping Allah or in taqwa.  When you are not practicing taqwa, your conduct can drift towards evil conduct to others.  Sins against others are less easily forgivable. If you have sinned against others while drunk, and they have not forgiven you before your death; then they will have their day in court on yaum i deen.  As the '***Hakeem***' (most fair and supreme judge), Allah has to be fair to the victims of your sin, and mercy becomes more complicated.  So it is not so much the zulm against yourself, but rather any wrong or bad speech you have committed against others in the intoxicated mind state that you need to be more concerned about.  If you have wronged others, make sure you have their forgiveness before you die.

I hope the above addressed the core of your question.  I would like to elaborate a bit more on the value of and purpose of tawba.

If Allah sbwtl had so willed he could have created us as robotic droids who never make mistakes and worship him perfectly.  This would have been easy for Allah to do.  Instead, the reality is that Allah created mankind out of '***sijeel***' dark mud or potter's clay.  A heart and soul that is dark is one that is not innocent and has much potential for evil conduct.

Quran 95.5: Then do We abase him (to be) the lowest of the low,-

A heart and soul that is like clay symbolizes that it is not a fixed form but rather one that can be molded into better more pious forms and indeed potentially the best of forms.

Quran 95.4: We have indeed created man in the best of forms,

We mold our heart and soul into better forms with righteous deeds, practicing worship (sala), charity (zekat), fasting (sawm), taqwa, and tawba.

When we realize the mistakes we make, and then sincerely make tawba to Allah, we mold our sijeel heart and soul to a better form that is closer to Allah.  If we never made the mistake we would have never made the tawba and not had the learning experience that gave us the increased understanding to come closer to Allah (***Yakeen***).

Quran 95.6: Except such as believe and do righteous deeds: For they shall have a reward unfailing.